# How to find new item in Dota 2 (reborn)

Tags: dota-2

I finished a game and got a random drop set for Spectre. I did not remember the name as every new item in armory used to show anyway.

But in the reborn I can't find this set at all. I've tried to filter 'Spectre' but it will literally find some cape of the spectre, but no items for Spectre (the hero).

How to easily find new items in reborn armory?

Answer (score 1):

In the Armory, items are sorted first by hero, then you can selected to order by **Date Acquired** :

[image]

You still have to scroll to Spectre but as far as I know there are no better option implemented at the moment. Valve is still working on making a better user experience in the Armory.

Answer (score 0):

In Armory, items are automatically sorted by heroes. You can navigate to "Spectre" and see it there.
Otherwise, you can go to "Heroes" tab on the top menu bar then go to the "Heroes =" subtab (between "Features" and "Global Items"). Then select "Spectre" in the Heroes list, you should see your items in there.